# how to create a ear file with datetime and version using pom.xml

Tags: maven, build

I have a maven project and respective pom.xml files. it is just a ear file, which is getting generated with my proejct name. but i want it dyanmic with projectname_datetime.ear file using pom.xml. Can you please give me a static example which will create a ear file with current dateand time of build number with major_minor or something link that.

Thanks in Advance.

Nilesh

Comment: You know that there exist a mechanism of SNAPSHOT releases ?

Answer (score 1):

See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2077869/116509. You'll also need to add

```
<build>      
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}-${maven.build.timestamp}
    </finalName>
```

However you should use probably be using -SNAPSHOT version numbers during development. If you want to be able to a refer to a definitive version, you can release that version. It's also possible to refer to a specific snapshot, see http://mojo.codehaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/examples/lock-snapshots.html.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `svn` for your source code management, Codehaus' [buildnumber-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/buildnumber-maven-plugin/) may be used to put the svn revision number into the manifest of any artifact you build, including snapshots.  The plugin has a goal to format timestamps too, if you need it.

Comment: No, I am using VSS repository