# How to access maven.build.timestamp for resource filtering

Tags: maven, timestamp, maven-3

I am using maven 3.0.4 and would like to make the build timestamp accessible to my application. For this, I'm putting a placeholder in a `.properties` file and let maven filter on build. While this is working fine for `${project.version}`, `${maven.build.timestamp}` is not substituted on filtering.

The property seems to be available on build - I can use it to modify the artifact name:

`<finalName>${project.artifactId}-${maven.build.timestamp}</finalName>`

So why is it not available for resource filtering? And, more importantly, how do I make it accessible?

Answer (score 258, accepted):

I have discovered [this article](https://dzone.com/articles/stamping-version-number-and), explaining that due to a [bug in maven](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MRESOURCES-99), the build timestamp does not get propagated to the filtering. The workaround is to wrap the timestamp in another property:

```xml
<properties>
   <timestamp>${maven.build.timestamp}</timestamp>
   <maven.build.timestamp.format>yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm</maven.build.timestamp.format>
</properties>
```

Filtering then works as expected for

```
buildTimestamp=${timestamp}
```

Comment: Just a note for others, I had problem with that, because I'm using Tomcat within Eclipse and it seems, that it's not working fine - replacement is ok in `target/${project}` folder, but in my actuall configuration Tomcat is not using this folder...

Comment: @Betlista yeah, server integration in eclipse seems to use the source directory. It was one of the reasons why I abandoned eclipse integration and use maven from command line.

Comment: Given there are multiple places in a pom where I need a timestamp, but in different formats (for example a file name and a build time string), how can I use `maven.build.timestamp.format` multiple times?

Comment: AFAIK this is not possible, since the format element is not subject to the individual properties. As workaround, you will probably have to put the string somewhere in a verbose format, so you can modify it later on programmatically.

Comment: No worky.  Filtering replaces `${timestamp}` with the literal string `${maven.build.timestamp}`.

Comment: It works, even in 3.3.9. Only trouble I had was that my property was also named ${timestamp} and was overwritten by the buildnumber-helper. So don't mix with that plugin.

Comment: Works perfectly, when used in conjunction with spring boot intializr

Comment: Works! But i get weird unix timestamp instead of formatted date. (example 1526536472093)

Comment: @TomazStoiljkovic do you define the format property for the timestamp? See the 'Available Variables' section in https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html

Comment: If you are using SpringBoot, you have to write `buildTimestamp=@timestamp@`

Comment: The bug has been "bandaided" so the properties declaration is no longer required, the other answers here...

Comment: If you use filtering within the maven-assembly-plugin v3.3.0, the ${maven.build.timestamp} is still not directly available, and you need to use the workaround noted here.  See also https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MASSEMBLY-603

Comment: @JulienFeniou Thanks!  `build.date=@timestamp@` worked for me and saved my afternoon!  Cheers.

Comment: maven.build.timestamp.format not working for me in production server. It runs in locally with intellij build. How can I update format?

Comment: Can use `${buildDate}`, without declaring extra properties (aside date format) ;-)

Answer (score 22):

I can confirm as of Maven 3.x `{maven.build.timestamp}` is "working" now.  They [work arounded](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc?view=revision&revision=1742471) the problem, apparently.  No additional `properties` workaround needed anymore.

However, be careful your "filtering" plugin (maven-resources-plugin) is up to date.  It needs to be relatively new, so if `mvn help:effective-pom` shows an old version (ex: 2.6), bump it to something newer, fixed it for me, 3.x ex:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.1.0</version>
</plugin>
```

`<properties><timestamp>...` workaround is no longer required...

This also cleared up, kind of, why it was working in IntelliJ but not the command line.  IntelliJ probably uses their own "modified/internal" maven constants, so it was working there, but not from maven command line.

Also note if you add a filtering resource directory to you pom, you may need to also "re-add" the default directory, it gets lost, ex:

```
  <resource>
    <directory>src/main/resources-filtered</directory> <!-- to get "maven.build.timestamp" into resource properties file -->
    <filtering>true</filtering>
  </resource>
  <resource>
    <directory>src/main/resources</directory> <!-- apparently have to add this is you have the other... -->
  </resource>
```

NB if you're using spring boot as your parent, you have to use @maven.build.timestamp@ [instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35417086/maven-resource-filtering-with-spring-boot-could-not-resolve-placeholder).  Also note if you're using spring boot there's a file `META-INF/build-info.properties` that is optionally created by the `spring-boot-maven-plugin` that you can [read](https://www.vojtechruzicka.com/spring-boot-version/) (spring provides a `BuildProperties` bean for convenience reading it).

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work yet for _maven-war-plugin_ (`<webResources><resource><filtering>`) :-( see [MWAR-415](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MWAR-415) -> so still have to use the workaround there

Comment: Different plugins do filtering differently. If you use filtering within the maven-assembly-plugin v3.3.0, the ${maven.build.timestamp} is still not directly available, and you need to use the `<properties><timestamp>...` workaround.  See also https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MASSEMBLY-603

Comment: build-info goal solution works as an alternative, but note that you have to put build-info goal before e.g. the repackage goal, if you already have repackage defined. as a sidenote, I couldn't make maven.build.timestamp.format work, so I ended up formatting the timestamp on the frontend - no big deal

Answer (score 5):

In order to enrich the Stackoverflow content for others, that like me, found this post as a way to solve the "problem" of `${maven.build.timestamp}`. This is not a maven bug, but an expected behavior of m2e, as can be seen in [this post](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=388874#c4).

Therefore, I believe that we can not expect the solution to be "corrected", since, from what I understand, the correction involves conceptual issues.

In my case, what I did was use the plugin (`buildnumber-maven-plugin`) as described in this [other post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16675480).

Comment: I found `buildnumber-maven-plugin` to have similar problems, namely that the variable it generates is only available in certain contexts, NOT filtering. You may or may not be able to overcome that by tinkering with the execution phase or goals, but the built-in solution seems so much simpler.

Answer (score 4):

Adding Maven properties at the pom project level doesn't take into account correct local Timezone, so timestamp may appear wrong :

```
<properties><timestamp>${maven.build.timestamp}</timestamp></properties>
```

Using the build-helper-maven-plugin applies the correct timezone and current daylight saving to the timestamp :

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>timestamp-property</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>timestamp-property</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <name>timestamp</name>
                        <pattern>yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss</pattern>
                        <timeZone>Europe/Zurich</timeZone>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
     </plugins>
     <resources>
         <resource>
             <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
             <filtering>true</filtering>
         </resource>
     </resources>
 </build>
```

When packaging, Maven will replace any token timestamp in /resources folder, e.g. resources/version.properties :

build.timestamp=${timestamp}

You can then load this properties file in your Application.

Comment: This has been superb reply, if not UTM applies.