# access maven.build.timestamp when writing a version.txt file

Tags: maven

Im trying to write out a version.txt file from my maven build, this is my version.txt file contents:

```
WarFilename: ${project.build.finalName}-${maven.build.timestamp}.war
BuildVersion: ${project.version} (build number ${build.number})
```

but when I go to the version.txt from the build output all of the values have been inserted except for ${maven.build.timestamp} which appears exactly like that. Is there anyway of injecting that info into a version.txt file ?

this is from my pom.xml file:

```
<resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
        <includes>
          <include>**/version.txt</include>
        </includes>
      </resource>
      <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        <filtering>false</filtering>
        <excludes>
          <exclude>**/version.txt</exclude>
        </excludes>
      </resource>
    </resources>
```

but I'm not sure how to configure it to be able to write the maven.build.timestamp value into the version.txt file, any help much appreciated, I'm completely new to maven.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

arghtype answered this with his comment:

> you could try this solution [stackoverflow.com/a/13228882/2417043](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13228882/2417043)