# Generate an HTML under webapp in a maven J2EE project when compilation completes

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee, compilation

I have a maven J2EE project and I would like to create an HTML file under the webapp directory to record the timestamp when compilation of the project is finished. Is there any plugin or method via which I could achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [maven resources plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/index.html) and its [filtering feature](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html). As variable you can use a timestamp as shown in the following (taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13228472/how-to-acces-maven-build-timestamp-for-resource-filtering)):

```
<properties>
   <timestamp>${maven.build.timestamp}</timestamp>
   <maven.build.timestamp.format>yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm</maven.build.timestamp.format>
</properties>
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you need to set the timestamp property in your pom.xml:

```
<properties>
    <maven.build.timestamp.format>dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss</maven.build.timestamp.format>
    <timestamp>${maven.build.timestamp}</timestamp>
</properties>
```

Secondly in the page you want to write the timestamp add something like:

```
<div id="builtby" class="span6">Version: @project.version@,
    Release Date: @timestamp@</div>
```

Finally, add the following to the `<build/>` section of your pom.xml, specifying the file(s) you want to filter.

```
<!-- USE THE WAR PLUGIN TO FILTER -->
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.2</version>
<configuration>
  <nonFilteredFileExtensions>
    <nonFilteredFileExtension>gif</nonFilteredFileExtension>
    <nonFilteredFileExtension>ico</nonFilteredFileExtension>
    <nonFilteredFileExtension>jpg</nonFilteredFileExtension>
    <nonFilteredFileExtension>png</nonFilteredFileExtension>
    <nonFilteredFileExtension>pdf</nonFilteredFileExtension>
  </nonFilteredFileExtensions>
  <webResources>
    <resource>
      <directory>src/main/webapp</directory>
      <filtering>true</filtering>
      <includes>
        <include>**/main.jsp</include>
      </includes>
    </resource>
  </webResources>
</configuration>
</plugin>
```