# How do I automatically embed version information into my Java application?

Tags: java, git, maven, intellij-idea

I'm developing a JavaFX 8 application using IntelliJ, Maven and Git.
I have an "about" window which shows the version number and build date.
At the moment, I have to manually change these each time I update the code.

Is there any way I can have my build process automatically generate version and date information and embed this into my code so it shows up in the about window?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retrieve version from maven pom.xml in code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3697449/retrieve-version-from-maven-pom-xml-in-code)

Comment: Also look at this one for the date part : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13228472/how-to-acces-maven-build-timestamp-for-resource-filtering

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use maven resource filtering.

Prepare file eg. `src/main/resources/version.properties` with content:

```
version=${project.version}
```

and add in your pom:

```
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
...
<build>
```

After build maven replace `${project.version}` for current project version.

In your project you can read this file and use in your abut window.

Read more about build timestamp property: [How to access maven.build.timestamp for resource filtering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13228472/how-to-acces-maven-build-timestamp-for-resource-filtering)