# Display Date on page for specific build in Wicket

Tags: java, maven, timestamp, wicket

I am using the Wicket framework for an application I designed.. I am not too familiar with interacting with Maven as a lot of that was already done for me. Currently every time I build and deploy a new version of the application I manually change the date in the markup that reflects the latest version date.

What I want to be able to do is set some sort of maven property that will create a time stamp each time I build the code.

How would I go about doing this? So how would I set the maven code, and then how would I reference the property inside my markup or Java to be reflected in the markup?

Currently I see:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.wicket</groupId>
        <artifactId>wicket-datetime</artifactId>
        <version>${wicket.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

already in the pom.xml file, but not sure if that's what I would use or how would I access this in my java code.

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/802677/adding-the-current-date-with-maven2-filtering

Answer (score 1):

you can use buildnumber-maven-plugin for versioning.
please check [this link](http://mojo.codehaus.org/buildnumber-maven-plugin/usage.html)

It has detailed steps of how to store the build number in your MANIFEST file.
Then you can access it via

```
String appServerHome = getServletContext().getRealPath("/");
File manifestFile = new File(appServerHome, "META-INF/MANIFEST.MF");

Manifest mf = new Manifest();
mf.read(new FileInputStream(manifestFile));
Attributes atts = mf.getMainAttributes();
System.out.println("Version: " + atts.getValue("Implementation-Version"));
System.out.println("Build: " + atts.getValue("Implementation-Build"));
```

Comment: Or you can use the `maven-war-plugin`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11951076/534877

Comment: great! didn't know about that. no need for this extra plugin. thnx Robert. I'll introduce it to my web project too.

Comment: So in the link referenced: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/802677/adding-the-current-date-with-maven2-filtering

it looks like there isn't anything written to the manifest. How would I access ${buildNumber} or one of the properties alternatives shown?

Comment: Any ideas from anyone?

Comment: check Robert's comment. i tried it and works fine. it writes the Build-Time entry in the manifest. try it yourself